# User resize able widgets like 3D modeling programs

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am using qt designer and python.  I want to make a layout where a user can drag widgets to control the size while at the same time scaling properly with the window.  Basically all 3d modeling programs have this function, usually it has a top left right and perspective view.  The user can drag the edges to resize each view and it will maintain that aspect ratio when the main window is resized.  My question is similar to this: [active resizing of widgets inside mainwindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233263/active-resizing-of-widgets-inside-mainwindow)  but I would like to do it in qt designer.

So what I have found is the layout horizontal/vertical splitter.  However I am only able to layout two widgets horizontally, and another two widgets horizontally, then grid layout.  This makes it look similar to what I want except I want the top and bottom horizontal layouts to also be re-size able.

Thanks

Edit:

I have been able to do this with putting both horizontal split views in a group box and then splitting the two group boxes, however that makes each widget independent and does not let the user grab the middle axis to control all 4 views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially asking for a splitter than works across two axes - no such standard widget exists.  So you will have to create your own.